# ¿Cómo crear excepción si no se cumple una consulta?

Tags: php, sql-server, php5

Tengo una pequeña consulta a una base de datos `sql server`. Estoy intentando crear un log, si por ejemplo la consulta fallase. Le he puesto un **if** que deberia ejecutarse si algún dato no está bien y crear un *log* al final de la consulta.

El problema que tengo, es que al hacer la prueba, no entra en el **if**

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

class funciones {

    function switchFuncion() {
        switch ($_GET["funcion"]) {
            case 'nombrefuncion': {

                    $query = new query();

 > Linea de Consulta a la base de datos
                    $result = $query->queryJson("select * from tabla ", "nombrefuncion");
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                    $arrayName = array('children' => $result);
                    echo json_encode($arrayName);

//// Si la variable $result falla deberia ejecutarse un error de log

                    if ($result->query($query) === FALSE) {

                        error_log("error");
                    }
                    ////////
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Esta es mi conexión

```
<?php

class conexion {

    public function conectar($base = "") {
        $serverName = "SQLEXPRESS";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "basedatos", "UID" => "user", "PWD" => "123", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if ($conn) {

            return $conn;
        } else {
            echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";

            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    }

}

$class = new conexion ();
$class->conectar();
?>
```

*Esta seria la clase query.php que contiene la clase conexion a la base de datos de `sql server`. creo que la condición if que le puse al archivo de consulta no funciona, bueno no tengo idea de como crear con este tipo de consulta una excepción lo del log se deberia ejecutar si la condición **if** en el archivo de consulta funcionara.*

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

class query {

    public function queryJson($sql = "", $funcion) {
        $cp1252_map = array(
            "\xc2\x80" => "\xe2\x82\xac", /* EURO SIGN */
            "\xc2\x82" => "\xe2\x80\x9a", /* SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK */
            "\xc2\x83" => "\xc6\x92", /* LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK */
            "\xc2\x84" => "\xe2\x80\x9e", /* DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK */
            "\xc2\x85" => "\xe2\x80\xa6", /* HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS */
            "\xc2\x86" => "\xe2\x80\xa0", /* DAGGER */
            "\xc2\x87" => "\xe2\x80\xa1", /* DOUBLE DAGGER */
            "\xc2\x88" => "\xcb\x86", /* MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT */
      
        );

        $class = new conexion ();
        $conn = $class->conectar();
        error_log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" . $sql);

        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

        if ($query === false) {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        } else {
            $result = "";

            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $result = $row;
            }

            return $result;
        }

        sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: que es $query->queryJson()?

Comment: queryJson es la variable que envía la consulta sql

Comment: Creo que necesitarias poner la clase `query()` tambien en la pregunta para ver que haces alli, pues no sabemos si alli tienes el problema. Con los datos actuales de tu pregunta tan solo puedo decirte que por defecto `error_log()` envia los errores al registro de errores del dominio de tu sistema y es allí donde debes consultar si graba algo o no.  Si cambias el `error_log()` por un `die("error")` te aseguraras mejor si estas entrando o no en ese `if`.

Comment: de hecho se puede incluir la clase query.php en el archivo de la consulta ya que esta clase solo contiene una conexión a la base de datos y algunas conversiones de caracteres

Comment: Yo lo que veo es que tienes un gran lío en la organización de tu código. Por ejemplo, creas una conexión dentro de `query`, lo cual significa que, en un contexto donde necesites hacer `N` consultas estarás creando `N` conexiones. Imaginemos un contexto donde haces consultas dentro de un bucle por ejemplo, si ese bucle tiene 1,000 iteracciones, estarás conectándote 1,000 veces. Creo que en primer lugar deberías clarificar/limpiar un poco tu código. Luego, podrás ver más claro que un simple `if` funcione o no, eso es lo de menos realmente en el lío de código que tienes.

Comment: Es más, quizá hasta **estás re-inventado la rueda**. ¿De qué tipo es tu conexión, es `mysqli`, es `PDO`? ¡Pues ambas tienen ya un método `query()`! ¿Qué justifica aquí que crees tu propio método `query`? ¿Tu conexión no extiende de la clase padre (sea `mysqli` sea `PDO`)? ¿Por qué no usas entonces su propio método `query()`? Insisto, conviene que clarifiques tu código y lo que pretendes lograr con todo esto. Simplemente te estarías ahogando en un vaso de agua.